# How to set animation on canvas.drawText() in android?

Tags: java, android, animation

Using `canvas.drawText()`, I have added some text on `bitmap image` but I want to animate this text like `fade in`, `fade out` and showing it **left to right**.

Comment: I think you can rely on redraw the text with change in alpha (0-1).